# Ubuntu does not load after successfull installation

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have Windows installed on my pc on partition (C), then I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on another partition. After the installation process finished successfully, Ubuntu asked to restart. Unfortunately, after the restart Windows was booted without showing a menu and asking me which OS to boot.

So how can I fix this problem and get a boot menu that allows me to boot Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

This problem happens to me as well. The way you you fix this problem.

First turn off secure boot and fast boot. and if that doesn’t work proceed to the following steps

1.boot from the Ubuntu disk.
2.Click try Ubuntu.
3.Get Boot repair
4. Run the recommended repair.

If you need better more clear instructions ill give you the link to the help site
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: You can [edit] your own posts, you know.

Comment: this has nothing to do with secure boot or EFI or even GRUB. The bios selects which os to boot. See the trouleshooting section of http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported "TROUBLESHOOTING

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP"

Comment: It did when i had this kind of trouble..